# How to configure s:url to return the absolute path, so that it doesn't get affected by html base?

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, struts

Using `<base href="<s:url value="/"/>" target="_blank">` resolves all images & stylesheets properly, when there are many namespaces like `/`, `/admin` etc.

But the action urls also get interrupted by `base` tag.

Suppose the current browser url is `http://context/admin/dashboard`

`<s:url value="clients" namespace="admin"/>` returns `clients` which in the browser gets resolved to `http://context/clients` instead of `http://context/admin/clients`

Is there a way to tell `s:url` to render absolute URLs instead of relative ?

http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/url.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1889898/1654265 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1889957/1654265

Comment: @AndreaLigios thanks for the above links. Is there any way by which `s:url` tag can render/return an absolute url ?

Comment: I don't know, but it's strange behaviour to ignore the namespace... can you post the generated html by an s:property of the s:url tag ? To be sure it is not s:a fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong value to the tag attribute `namespace`. The `namespace` value should correspond to the package attribute and use the path value calculated from the web content root. So, if you have declared the `namespace="/admin"` this value should be used to the corresponding `url` tag attribute.

```
<s:url action="clients" namespace="/admin"/>
```

The result outputs to HTML, and you could see what value is rendered.

Comment: actually, using just `admin` (without slash) works. Although I should be using `action` attribute, not the value attribute. After using `action` instead of `value` it rendered relatively good path which didn't got affected by `html base` tag.

Comment: yes, it works because the `url` tag build the URL which is mapped to the action in the namespace specified and if it fails to build the current action URL is used which is relative.